# How can I mask my wordpress page ids to show just the domain instead

Tags: wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have wordpress and everytime I make a page it makes a id for that page.
Is there a way to instead of showing

www.mydomain.com/?page_id=97

to just show
www.mydomain.com
instead no matter what page is shown

I am sure mod rewrite is used but .htaccess is always a mystery to me.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I hope you don't mind if I ask, but why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know mod_rewrite cant do this. It has no way to deduce which page to go from a single top level url.

There are two possibilities that I can think of -

1) You can have sef urls - http://www.mydomain.com/some-page

2) You can do exactly what you want through iframes

Comment: It is good to point out that if you use option #2, search engines will fail at indexing your website properly. Apart from that, #2 is a solution to achieve exactly what you want.